# How do I sum the first value in each tuple in a list of tuples in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples (always pairs) like this:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (5, 7), (2, 1)]
```

I'd like to find the sum of the first items in each pair, i.e.:

```
0 + 2 + 5 + 2
```

How can I do this in Python? At the moment I'm iterating through the list:

```
sum = 0
for pair in list_of_pairs:
   sum += pair[0]
```

I have a feeling there must be a more Pythonic way.

Comment: Ben if you're still around, would you consider accepting SilentGhost's answer instead of mine?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In modern versions of Python I'd suggest [what SilentGhost posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/638069/56541) (repeating here for clarity):

> ```
> sum(i for i, j in list_of_pairs)
> ```

---

In an earlier version of this answer I had suggested this, which was necessary because SilentGhost's version didn't work in the version of Python (2.3) that was current at the time:

```
sum([pair[0] for pair in list_of_pairs])
```

Now that version of Python is beyond obsolete, and SilentGhost's code works in all currently-maintained versions of Python, so there's no longer any reason to recommend the version I had originally posted.

Answer (score 47):

```
sum(i for i, j in list_of_pairs)
```

will do too.

Comment: I thought so at first, but when I tried that in the quickest Python I could access it raised a syntax error :-( Turns out I was testing on Python 2.3, though... +1 anyway

Comment: +1: prefer this -- tuples have a fixed size and you usually know what the size is.

Comment: I like this approach, too. But Davids solution works with n-tuples, too, which might be preferable, depending on the actual problem.

Comment: I should probably note that this code is about 15% faster than the one from accepted answer.

Comment: `i` and `j` should be replaced with `first` and `second` ;)

Comment: `i` and `j` are fine. If I had to type `first` and `second` for _every_ sequence iteration, I'd have bleeding stumps for fingers within a man-month.

Answer (score 24):

I recommend:

```
sum(i for i, _ in list_of_pairs)
```

*Note*:

Using the variable `_`(or `__` to avoid confliction with the alias of `gettext`) instead of `j` has at least two benefits:

1. `_`(which stands for placeholder) has better readability
2. `pylint` won't complain:  "Unused variable 'j'"

Answer (score 6):

If you have a very large list or a generator that produces a large number of pairs you might want to use a generator based approach. For fun I use `itemgetter()` and `imap()`, too. A simple generator based approach might be enough, though.

```
import operator
import itertools

idx0 = operator.itemgetter(0)
list_of_pairs = [(0, 1), (2, 3), (5, 7), (2, 1)]
sum(itertools.imap(idx0, list_of_pairs))
```

Note that `itertools.imap()` is available in Python >= 2.3. So you can use a generator based approach there, too.

Comment: Not really faster than the other two solutions.

Comment: Speed is always good, and should at least be mentioned in the answers.

Comment: Then I suggest a solution in C or Assembler.

Comment: The cases for this approach are clearly laid out in the first sentence of the answer.

Comment: **You've got a syntax error here** – albeit an extremely _minor_ syntax error. The last line should be suffixed by an additional `")"` delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

Obscure (but fun) answer:

```
>>> sum(zip(*list_of_pairs)[0])
9
```

Or when zip's are iterables only this should work:

```
>>> sum(zip(*list_of_pairs).__next__())
9
```

Comment: mmm, 'zip' object has no attribute 'next'.

Comment: it does have attribute __next__, however

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample code, you can also specify the list range.

```
def test_lst_sum():
    lst = [1, 3, 5]
    print sum(lst)  # 9
    print sum(lst[1:])  # 8

    print sum(lst[5:])  # 0  out of range so return 0
    print sum(lst[5:-1])  # 0

    print sum(lst[1: -1])  # 3

    lst_tp = [('33', 1), ('88', 2), ('22', 3), ('44', 4)]
    print sum(x[1] for x in lst_tp[1:])  # 9
```

Answer (score -2):

```py
s,p=0,0
for i in l:
  s=s+i[0]
  p=p+i[1]
print(tuple(s,p))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it