# sum each value in a list of tuples

Tags: python, performance, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples similar to this:

```
l = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 0)]
```

I want to create a simple one-liner that will give me the following result:

```
r = (25, 20) or r = [25, 20] # don't care if tuple or list.
```

Which would be like doing the following:

```
r = [0, 0]
for t in l:
  r[0]+=t[0]
  r[1]+=t[1]
```

I am sure it is something very simple, but I can't think of it.

Note: I looked at similar questions already:

[How do I sum the first value in a set of lists within a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663024/how-do-i-sum-the-first-value-in-a-set-of-lists-within-a-tuple)

[How do I sum the first value in each tuple in a list of tuples in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638048/how-do-i-sum-the-first-value-in-each-tuple-in-a-list-of-tuples-in-python)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python element-wise tuple operations like sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497885/python-element-wise-tuple-operations-like-sum)

Comment: @CiroSantilli: it is not a duplicate. The question that you've linked works with *two* tuples. This question about a *list* of tuples. The transposition is the essential part of the solution. Though the answers work almost verbatim in both cases. Still `a,b` tuples and `a_list_of_tuples` are different (the diffence might be exposed in what solution is the most efficient).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use `zip()` and `sum()`:

```
In [1]: l = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 0)]

In [2]: [sum(x) for x in zip(*l)]
Out[2]: [25, 20]
```

or:

```
In [4]: map(sum, zip(*l))
Out[4]: [25, 20]
```

`timeit` results:

```
In [16]: l = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 0)]*1000

In [17]: %timeit [sum(x) for x in zip(*l)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit [sum(x) for x in izip(*l)]       #prefer itertools.izip
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit map(sum, zip(*l))
100 loops, best of 3: 1.48 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit map(sum, izip(*l))                #prefer itertools.izip
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop
```

Comment: O_O can't believe how simple that was, how could I have forgot about `zip`? thanks. Which is more efficient? the `map` or `list-comprehension` method?

Comment: `map` sometimes outperforms `list comprehension` when used with built-in functions.

Comment: Out of interest, what does the asterisk mean when you go `zip(*l)`?

Comment: @nick_w for `zip()` when used with * acts like unzipping a list. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: This can be made slightly faster by using 'map' instread of a loop. As follows:

map(sum,zip(*res))

Comment: @jhrf Perhaps you should look at the answer one more time.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary OPPS! Sorry for not reading the answer completely. I am surprised, however, that map fails to beat an inline for loop even using izip (even if the difference is slight). My understanding was that inline for-loops were slower than map. Am I wrong about this? Pardon my silly comment!

Comment: Just want to mention that the timing results is for Python 2, since in Python 3 `zip` is an iterator this the `itertools.izip` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

Without using zip

```
sum(e[0] for e in l), sum(e[1] for e in l)
```

Answer (score 3):

I want to add something to the given answer:

If I have an array of dict e.g.

```
l = [{'quantity': 10, 'price': 5},{'quantity': 6, 'price': 15},{'quantity': 2, 'price': 3},{'quantity': 100, 'price': 2}]
```

and i want to obtain two (or more) sums of calculated quantity over the values e.g. sum of quantities and of price*quantity

I can do:

```
(total_quantity, total_price) = (
sum(x) for x in zip(*((item['quantity'],
                       item['price'] * item['quantity'])
                      for item in l)))
```

Instead of:

```
total_quantity = 0
total_price = 0
for item in l:
     total_quantity += item['quantity']
     total_price += item['price'] * item['quantity']
```

Maybe the first solution is less readable, but is more "pythonesque" :)

Comment: What does that add to Ashwini's answer? The question is not about a list of dicts

Comment: you're right, but it adds something about using sum and zip for complex operations. I was looking for something like that, I've found this answer and I used it for my own problem, which was about dicts. Thus I thought it would be nice to share my solution with somebody else who could have my same issue.