# How can I do the summatory of elements in a list of lists in python?

Tags: python, list, iteration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sum each value in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180866/sum-each-value-in-a-list-of-tuples)

I need help with this problem, Thank you in advance for your colaboration.
I would like obtein this:

```
result=[12,15,18]
```

from

```
a= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I am trying with the code below that works, but I would like find a general form for to do this in the case the internal lists could be variables.

```
lista=[[5, 7, 9], [8, 11, 13], [11, 13, 15]]

b2 = [lista [0][i]+ lista [1][i] + lista [2][i] for i in range(len(lista))]

print (b2)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: This smells like homework.

Comment: Thank you very much Ashwini Chaudhary, the question was duplicated, this explication works perfect, very kind of you part.

Comment: @user1965825 glad the helped.

Comment: Heck, list comprehension works too, but is a bit convoluted. `[sum((a[i][j] for i in xrange(len(a)))) for j in xrange(len(a[0]))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
# a is some list
b2 = [0]*len(a[0])
for x in a:
    for y in range(len(x)):
         b2[y] += x[y]
print(b2)
```

Comment: This is very un-pythonic compared to `zip()` based solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
a= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
result = map(sum, zip(*a))
print result
```

Comment: complementing the helpful answer of Jun HU in python 3 could be:

lista=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
g=[]
for i in map(sum, zip(*lista)):
        g.append(i)
print (g)

Thanks,