# How to sum variables seperately that is returned from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

I wish to do a summation like this:

```
tot_males = 0
tot_females = 0
for groups in itertools.chain.from_iterable(self.class): # Iterates over all the class
    current_males, current_females = groups.number_of_persons() # Returns how many males and females there are in one group
    tot_males += current_males
    tot_females += current_females

return tot_males, tot_females # EDIT: Corrected return values
```

Is there any way to do this summation without a for loop? I am just curious. This is the best solution I have created so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sum each value in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180866/sum-each-value-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: It would give something like `[sum(x) for x in zip(*[g.number_of_persons() for g in itertools.chain.from_iterable(self.class)])]` Also careful your return is wrong you don't return the sum. I'd you could do now directly : `return *[sum(x) for x in zip(*[g.number_of_persons() for g in itertools.chain.from_iterable(self.class)])]`

Comment: Ah yes! My return is wrong! I will fix that. And that is exactly what I was looking for, I tried googling, but didn't google well enough. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can post it as an answer and I can accept it or I can delete the post,  what do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the solution given from [`sum value of list of tuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180866/sum-each-value-in-a-list-of-tuples#answers) You could do the following

```
return *[sum(x) for x in zip(*[g.number_of_persons() for g in itertools.chain.from_iterable(self.class)])]
```

---

Of course it could be splitted for better comprehension

```
groups = [g.number_of_persons() for g in itertools.chain.from_iterable(self.class)]
sums = [sum(x) for x in zip(*groups)]
tot_males, tot_females = *sums
return tot_males, tot_females
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with `lambda` function and `numpy`.

```
pairs = numpy.array(list(map(lambda g: g.number_of_persons(), 
                          itertools.chain.from_iterable(self.class))))

return numpy.sum(pairs, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that with the method `sum()`:

```
return sum[grps.num_of_per()[0] for grps in itertools.chain.from_iterable(self.class)], sum[grps.num_of_per()[1] for grps in chain.from_iterable(self.class)]
```