# Summing the first value in each tuple in a list over a specific range in Python

Tags: python-2.7, tuples

My question is based on an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638048/how-do-i-sum-the-first-value-in-each-tuple-in-a-list-of-tuples-in-python) and I can't find to figure out (nor find) the subsequent step I need.

Say I do have the same list of tuples, namely:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (5, 7), (2, 1)]
```

Also I wish to find the sum of the first values in each pair, which could be done by the simple pythonic:

```
sum([pair[0] for pair in list_of_pairs])
```

as provided by [David Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56541/david-z). However, in my case I only wish to sum from the first first value up until a following first value, say the first value at index N = 2.
Thus, only calculate the sum of:

```
0 + 2 + 5
```

I have been trying things like:

```
sum([pair[0] for pair in list_of_pairs[:N])
```

but without success. Can anyone provide me with an elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were very close to the solution

This works for me :

```
N=2

sum([pair[0] for pair in list_of_pairs[0:N+1]])
```

If you wants from middle then you can do this :

```
N=3
M=1
print sum([pair[0] for pair in list_of_pairs[M:N+1]])
```