# Find the sum of first element in a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a nested list `newlist`. I want to find the sum of values like `'£2.99','£4.99'`. The effective sum would be like `2.99+4.99+2.99` etc

```
newlist = [['£2.99', '1', '16-Feb-19'], ['£4.99', '2', '16-Feb-19'], ['£2.99', '1', '15-Feb-19']....]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate and show a [mcve] that "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help. Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sum the first value in each tuple in a list of tuples in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638048/how-do-i-sum-the-first-value-in-each-tuple-in-a-list-of-tuples-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `list comprehensions` to solve this:

```
l= [['£2.99', '1', '16-Feb-19'], ['£4.99', '2', '16-Feb-19'], ['£2.99', '1', '15-Feb-19']]

# 1. replace() will replace the first argument '£' with second argument (empty space).
# 2. map(): It takes two arguments, where first argument is the datatype 
#           you wish to convert to and second argument is value we want to convert.
# 3. list(): Since the list comprehension gives us the list of mapping, where as we need to 
#            convert it to proper proper list with numbers, and that's why we use list() 
#            to do so.
sum(list(map(float,[i[0].replace('£','') for i in l])))
    10.97
```

Comment: Same as other answer @cph_sto, `sum` can take a generator, no need to extract a list from the map. There's actually no need for the map at all, as you only have a string in each iteration having sliced with the first element

Comment: @yatu I noticed that. But, I would let it remain that way as other people could see that some of my steps were redundant, and they refrain from doing so.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sum([float(i[0].replace('£','')) for i in a])
```

As @darksky mentioned, I will explain here a little more:

`sum` will returns the sum of one iterable item.

`float` will cast Strings to float like `"2.99"` --> `2.99`

and Replace is obvious.

the output will be:

```
10.97
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a generator expression and `sum` the first element in each list (simply slice it with `[1:]` to skip the `£`):

```
my_list = [['£2.99', '1', '16-Feb-19'], ['£4.99', '2', '16-Feb-19'],
           ['£2.99', '1', '15-Feb-19']]


sum(float(l[0][1:]) for l in my_list)
# 10.97
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different answer:

```
data = [['£2.99', '1', '16-Feb-19'], ['£4.99', '2', '16-Feb-19'], ['£2.99', '1', '15-Feb-19']]
sum = 0.0

for item in data:
    formatted = item[0][1:]
    sum += float(formatted)
```

After that code completes, `sum` will be equal to 10.97, the result.