# What does the following line of code mean and how does python interpreter handle this

Tags: python, list, tuples

I was looking at the answer at following link 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/638069
but couldn't understand how does it perform

```
sum(i for i, j in list_of_pairs)
```

I think it will only sum up the first value of the tuples in the

```
list_of_pairs
```

Comment: Note that the question is titled "How do I sum the first value in each tuple". So your analysis is likely correct.

Comment: Read about generator expressions and play around with the line to understand it. E. g. you can replace the "sum" by "list" to see which items are generated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it only sums the first value of the tuples in the list.